# How to get user code for device code flow in identity server 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I'm trying to use Device Code Flow which is already implemented in IdentityServer4 but in the documentation, I couldn't find anything useful about Device Code Flow. I find out an example of Device Code Flow but I don't understand what is User Code, how to get or save it.

Here is the basic service which is used to get the context of authorization.

```
    private readonly IDeviceFlowInteractionService _interaction;

    public DeviceController(
        IDeviceFlowInteractionService interaction)
    {
        _interaction = interaction;
        _clientStore = clientStore;
        _resourceStore = resourceStore;
        _events = eventService;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    private async Task<DeviceAuthorizationViewModel> BuildViewModelAsync(string userCode, DeviceAuthorizationInputModel model = null)
    {
        var request = await _interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(userCode);
        // Some code ...
        return null;
    }
```

As you can see above I've use GetAuthorizationContext which has parameter userCode but I didn't understand how to get this code ? or where to save it. In the documentation, I didn't find anything about UserCode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a sample application](https://github.com/leastprivilege/AspNetCoreSecuritySamples/tree/aspnetcore21/DeviceFlow) built by one of the IdentityServer maintainers showing how to utilize Device Flow.

The client is going to need to make a request to the device authorization endpoint to have a code generated. Indicated by line 38 of [this file](https://github.com/leastprivilege/AspNetCoreSecuritySamples/blob/aspnetcore21/DeviceFlow/Client/Program.cs), once a code has been generated it should be displayed to the user.

The user can then enter the code on your web application to be submitted to the `DeviceController` you built above.